# (JUnitCore.runClasses ) How Junit file is processed by 'Main' class in Java?

Tags: java, junit

### Junit Test Case file Below

```
import org.junit.Test;    
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class TestJunit {
    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        String str= "Junit is working fine";
        assertEquals("Junit is working fine",str);
    }
}
```

================================================================

### Main Class File Below

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunit.class);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
    }
}
```

Above code is working fine.
Please let me know how the main class is processing the Junit file.
I cannot understand the main class .
Please explain

Comment: You could look at the source to try and step through what is happening. It might inspire more specific questions. https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using reflection. `TestJUnit.class` is the `Class` object representing your `TestJUnit` class. This object allows getting the metadata about the class: its name, its base class, its methods, annotations on the methods, etc.

So, basically, JUnitCore looks for all the public void methods without argument annotated with `@Test`, and executes them. If one of the method throws an unexpected exception, it's an error. If one of the methods makes an assertion fail, it's a failure, and if the method complete normally, it's a success.